# communication between ear modules

Tags: javascript, rest, jakarta-ee, jboss, ear

Hi i am working on a project where there is a REST service deployed as part of an ear and our application is deployed as a different ear . (let me call is restapi.ear and myapplication.ear) .

We have a GUI deployed in myapplication.ear , but we want to access some REST services through our GUI. So basically the js file within the myapplication.ear will be using the REST APIs exposed by restapi.ear .

I read about the cross domain js problems so would like to get suggestions about how to allow this communication . What are the best practices which i have to follow to allow this integration.

Comment: Are these EARs deployed in different domains or even subdomains? (E.g. `www.restapi.com` - `www.myapp.com` or `restapi.myserver.com` - `myapp.myserver.com`) Normally the application server would deploy the web apps in different paths under the same domain (e.g. `myserver.com/restapi` - `myserver.com/myapp`) and there should be no problem calling `myserver.com/restapi` from a page under `myserver.com/myapp`.

Comment: They are in different domains , i tried writing sample client from my domain and it worked , but will there be any cases (like in cluster mode) where this may not work ?

Comment: If they are in different domains, take a look at something like the answer from Lifecube.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your server to support [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)
You can take a look tomcat one for example [tomcat 7 CORS_Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter)